# Oracle ODP.net Managed driver can't find the Oracle.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, membership-provider, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I've been using oracle unmanaged driver and now I'm just trying to use Oracle ODP.net Managed driver for my web api 2 application.

I installed it using 
    PM> Install-Package odp.net.managed
Then made "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" Local copy true.
Removed reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll

I use "OracleMembershipProvider" to login and when I run my application it gives me the following error.

Could not load type 'Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and configure "Oracle Providers for  ASP.NET".

At the time of this writing, the Oracle products on Nuget were not put there by Oracle. I recommend you obtain your software here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html